# Why doesn't `restore` display my UTF-8 encoded filenames correctly in interactive mode?

Tags: backup, character-encoding, unicode, restore, dump

When using the interactive mode of the `restore` utility to restore backups made with `dump` UTF-8-encoded filenames doesn't display correctly, see example below. The `??`s should be `ö`s ...

```
$ sudo restore -if dumpfile
Dump tape is compressed.
restore > ls
./somedir:
lagerl??fSelma_k??rkarlen.txt

restore >
```

How come? What are the solutions do this problem?

The dump and the restore are performed on the same machine, that has the locale set as follows:

```
$ locale
LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=sv:en_US:en
```

Comment: may be you use old dump package.

Comment: Thanks, I believe I'm using the latest version `dump 0.4b44 (using libext2fs 1.42.8 of 20-Jun-2013)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code has this:

```
for (cp = fp->fname; *cp; cp++)
    if (!vflag && (*cp < ' ' || *cp >= 0177))
        *cp = '?';
```

So it looks like it will substitute `'?'` for non-printable-ASCII characters unless you give `restore` the `-v` option or, in interactive mode, type the `verbose` command.